# Why TTFB on IE is slower than Chrome / Firefox like 10 times?

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have crazy with this couple day,
Same Domain, same page, load on Chrome / Firefox for max 4 seconds. but with IE, the TTFB is 12 seconds:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150718_7G_10S/
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150718_Z5_148/

URL is:
http://appraisals.wintrustmortgage.com/tandem/login/?

Anyone can give me any recommend ?

Comment: First of all, let's be clear. Are you talking about page load time or TTFB? Because TTFB has nothing to do with your browser, whereas page load time does, as this includes things like parsing the DOM, style rendering (CSS engine), and possibly even javascript parsing/execution, which can absolutely differ from one client UA implementation to another. TTFB, however, will never differ based on browser, but based on your server's time start serving up the first byte of the response. In other words, TFFB has nothing to do with the client and page load time has nothing to do with the server.

Comment: "... and page load time has nothing to do with the server" <- except this end, I agree. [Page load time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Page_load_time) includes the time to download the page content. Thus, it is influenced by the server.

Answer (score 2):

#### What TTFB (*Time To First Byte*) Includes

- Time the server spends processing a request after it is received
- Time the server spends sending the first byte of the response back to the client

#### What TTFB Does NOT Include

- Time spent negotiating any domain name resolution (i.e. *DNS*)
- Time the client takes to connect to the server
- Time spent negotiating any SSL connection
- Time spent between end points sending packets (i.e. *network latency*)
- Time the server spends receiving a request
- Time spent consuming a response by the client (i.e. *client read time*)
- Time client spends parsing/rendering/executing the response or making/waiting-on any subsequent requests to/from the server

#### Differences between Chrome/Firefox and IE

IE does *not* measure TTFB. It measures TTLB (*Time To **Last** Byte*), which is very different. Please see [Using Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools Network Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

> **Response** - The offset value that is taken when a response is first received from the server. The duration is the time between that start time and when the last byte is received from the server.

The difference is clearly outlined in Chrome's detailed break down of the network timed events

[image]

As opposed to IE's horrid implementation of this...

[image]

Simply put, your browser has no bearing on TTFB. IE's developer tools are just  generally less comprehensive and useful in this regard.

The blue/teal-ish block, which is 1.74 seconds non-inclusive, represents time spent waiting on all that response data down the last byte. That means network latency can effect this measurement. So for all we know, the TTFB was still within ~300 milliseconds and the remainder of that ~1.4 seconds was spent downloading the rest of the response.

I hope that clarifies the misconception here.